# Presentation of UIHostingController glitches with .overCurrentContext modal presentation style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am trying to display a `UIHostingController` which shows my SwiftUI Popup on screen - however, the presentation glitches and the presented view controller is somewhere stuck in the topmost left corner (see picture, the glitching hosting controller is inside the red circle).

This only occurs if I display another View controller before my hosting controller. So, if nothing was presented before my hosting controller, everything works fine.

Things also work fine, if I set my `UIHostingController`'s `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet` - however, that's not a solution for me since I need the behavior of `.overCurrentContext` for my use case.

So, in short, I **do experience a glitch** when:

- an arbitrary view controller is presented (using `self.present(...)`) at some point
- ***before*** my `UIHostingViewController` is presented.

I **do not** get that glitch when:

- I only display the UIHostingViewController

[image]

### Code

I receive the described behavior using the following code:

```swift
// First, I display an ActivitySheet
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [someItems], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(ac, animated: true)

// then I present my ViewController using overCurrentContext, after the ActivityViewController was dismissed
let myPopupVC = MyPopupVC()
        
myPopupVC.isModalInPresentation = true
myPopupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // error would not occur if this was .formSheet, but I need .overCurrentContext for my use case.
myPopupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

self.definesPresentationContext = true
self.present(self, animated: true)
```

Both modal presentations are the result of button clicks in my interface. The `UIActivityViewController` is displayed when a share button is clicked, and the popup is displayed when the leave button is pressed (to confirm the user is sure they want to do that).

### What I assume

My first thought was that this could have something to do with the `UIHostingController` being presented by the dismissed activity sheet, however, that wouldn't make sense since it is freed from memory according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html) on view controller dismissal (chapter *"Dismissing a presented View Controller"*).

I therefore don't understand why this is happening.

**Does anyone know why this behavior arises and, most importantly, how I can fix it *using* `.overCurrentContext` as my modal presentation style?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that I set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, which resulted in the `UIHostingController`'s view to lack information needed to position itself correctly.

Therefore, make sure that `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` remains `true` if you modally present a `UIHostingController`.